# Как передать и принять GET запрос?

Tags: php, парсер, get

Есть есть index.html, страница с формой

```
<form id="slick-login" action="parser.php">
    <label for="offset">Сдвиг:</label><input type="text" name="offset" class="placeholder" placeholder="Сдвиг" value="1">
    <label for="count">Количество:</label><input type="text"  name="count" class="placeholder" placeholder="Число постов" value="49">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Необходимо после нажатия "отправить" передать данные offset и count и подставить в нужные поля parser.php

```
$request_params = [   
'domain' => 'lost',
'offset' => 'offset подставился сюда',
'count' => 'count подставился сюда',
'version' => 10,];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$request_params = [   
'domain' => 'lost',
'offset' => $_GET['offset'],
 'count' => $_GET['count'],
'version' => 10,];
```

Comment: Валентина, Спасибо!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я он! )) Но, пожалуйста ))

Comment: Хотя вопрос был про GET, чисто ради полноты картины добавлю, что аргументы POST можно получить из массива $_POST, а массив $_REQUEST наиболее универсальный, так как объединяет содержимое и $_GET, и $_POST, и даже $_COOKIE.